# React native list map() method add custom element below selected Item

Tags: react-native

When Item with id=1 selected
then the element appear below
the selected Item. And when
unselected the element disappear.

This is a list with map() method.
The element should be inside the
SrollView like Item
**But isn’t a new Item**
[image]

I have this code that can create a new Item below the selected Item but I don't want to create a new Item but only appear a custom View(element) like above.
Expo Snack> https://snack.expo.dev/@stefanosalexandrou/honest-cashew

Answer (score 1):

You could store the selected index in a `state`, which you are already doing. Then, use `conditional rendering` in order to render a custom component below the selected item. Furthermore, if a selected item is pressed again, set the state to `undefined`.

The `handleOnPress` function.

```js
function handleOnPress(idx) {
  setSelectedId(prev => prev === idx ? undefined : idx)
}
```

The updated render function.

```js
 <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View>

          {data.map((person, index) => {

            const backgroundColor = index === selectedId ? "#6e3b6e" : "#f9c2ff";

            return (
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity 
                  onPress={() => handleOnPress(index)}
                  style={{
                    padding:20,
                    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                    marginBottom:20,
                  }}
                >
                  <Text>{person.name}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {
                  index === selectedId ? <View style={{backgroundColor: "red", height: 100, width: "100%"}}><Text>Custom Super Component Visible on press of above item </Text></View> : null
                }
              </View>
             
            );
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

I have added a dummy component if the index is selected.

However, you might want to select multiple items one after the other and deselect them individually while having the same effect. For doing so, we change the `state` to store an array of indices instead.

The updated state and handleOnPress function.

```js
  const [selectedIndices, setSelectedIds] = useState([]);

  function handleOnPress(idx) {
    if (selectedIndices.includes(idx)) {
      setSelectedIds(prev => prev.filter(i => i !== idx))
    } else {
      setSelectedIds(prev => [...prev, idx])
    }
  }
```

The updated render function.

```js
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View>

          {data.map((person, index) => {

            const backgroundColor = selectedIndices.includes(index) ? "#6e3b6e" : "#f9c2ff";

            return (
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity 
                  onPress={() => handleOnPress(index)}
                  style={{
                    padding:20,
                    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                    marginBottom:20,
                  }}
                >
                  <Text>{person.name}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {
                  selectedIndices.includes(index) ? <View style={{backgroundColor: "red", height: 100, width: "100%"}}><Text>Custom Super Component Visible on press of above item </Text></View> : null
                }
              </View>
             
            );
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how can the new element be out of the Selected Item like new Item and not in the same box?

Comment: Add a vertical margin to the outer view of the new element.

Comment: The problems isn't the margin is that I want this like new Item because I also want add state to change onPress the zIndex of the selected Item to infront of all other items in ScrollView. I done this but I don't the element also go Infront  but stay back with other not selected Items.

Comment: Any idea to achieve above?